# Cannot access '/dev/ttyACM0': No such file or directory

Tags: tty, ttyusb

So i need to use '/dev/ttyACM0'. I try to show all USB option available with:
`~$ sudo dmesg | grep tty`, and i get

```
[    0.098062] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[  291.890275] cdc_acm 2-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  825.280387] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 1071.046356] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 1143.484587] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 1467.838416] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2074.551625] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2137.536720] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2196.153047] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2307.305412] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

But when i try `sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/ttyACM0`, i get `chmod: cannot access '/dev/ttyACM0': No such file or directory`.

Why it said that no such file or directory when it's clearly that i have ttyACM0?

Comment: Given the amount of times it's being logged, perhaps it is hot pluggable and another module is taking it over.